# como faço para formatar o valor de uma variavel double no android?

Tags: java, android, xml

estou fazendo um pequeno aplicativo que tem como objetivo de calcular o IMC de uma pessoa, mas não estou conseguindo formatar a saida do valor para apenas duas casas decimais sempre fica algo como: 22.222222 ou 31.23232322 etc... já tentei usar o "%.2f", porém o TextView n aceita.
alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3):

Experimente assim:

```
double dub = 31.2323232;
meuEditText.setText(String.format( "%.2f", dub ));
```